# Need correct database structure to reduce the size

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, entity-relationship

I want to design my database correctly. Maybe someone could help me with that.

I have a device which writes every 3s around 100 keys/values to a table.
Someone suggested to store it like this:

> ^ timestamp ^ key1 ^ key2 ^ [...] ^ key150 ^
>
> | 12/06/12 | null | 2243466 | [...]   | null ^

But I think thats completely wrong and not dynamic. Because I could have many null values.
So I tried to do my best and designed it how I learned it at school:
http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/?keyword=tempidi

Here is the problem that I write for every value the timestamp which means within 100values it would be always the same and produce large amount of data.

Could someone give a me hint how to reduce the database size? Am I basically correct with my ERM?

Comment: Are you concerned with the disk space used by writing the same timestamp to 100 rows?

Comment: Yes.

My calculation is:
100 values * 16bytes * 24 (h) * 60(min) * 60(s) * 30 (month) = 3.8GB /month

Comment: Whoever suggested that it be stored like that should not be recommending database models.

Comment: @YannicDoNotText The answer below details a good model. The model you present has columns which should translated to rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *must* implement a key-value store in MySQL, it doesn't make any sense to make it more complicated than this.

```
create table key_value_store (
  run_time datetime not null,
  key_name varchar(15) not null,
  key_value varchar(15) not null,
  primary key (run_time, key_name)
);
```

If the average length of both your keys and values is 10 bytes, you're looking at about 86 million rows and 2.5GB per month, and you don't need any joins. If all your values (column key_value) are either integers or floats, you can change the data type and reduce space a little more.

One of the main problems with implementing key-value stores in SQL is that, unless all values are the same data type, you have to use something like varchar(n) for all values. You lose type safety and declarative constraints. (You can't check that the value for key3 is between 1 and 15, while the value for key7 is between 0 and 3.)

---

**Is this feasible?**

This kind of structure (known as "EAV"--Google that) is a well-known table design anti-pattern. Part of the problem is that you're essentially storing columns as rows. (You're storing column names in key_value_store.key_name.)  If you *ever* have to write out data in the format of a normal table, you'll discover three things.

1. It's hard to write queries to output the right format.
2. It takes forever to run. If you have to write hundreds of columns, it might never run to completion.
3. You'll wish you had much faster hardware. Much, *much* faster hardware.

**What I look for**

- Opportunities to group keys into logical tables. This has to do with the first design, and it might not apply to you. It sounds like your application is basically storing a log file, and you don't know which keys will have values on each run.
- Opportunities to reduce the number of rows. I'd ask, "Can we write less often?" So I'd be looking at writing to the database every 5 or 6 seconds instead of every 3 seconds, assuming that means I'm writing fewer rows. (The real goal is fewer rows, not fewer writes.)
- The right platform. PostgreSQL 9.2 might be a better choice for this. Version 9.2 has index-only scans, and it has an hstore module that implements a key-value store.

**Test before you decide**

If I were in your shoes, I'd build this table in both MySQL and PostgreSQL. I'd load each with about a million rows of random-ish data. Then I'd try some queries and reports on each. (Reports are important.) Measure the performance. Increase the load to 10 million rows, retune the server and the dbms, and run the same queries and reports again. Measure again.

Repeat with 100 million rows. Quit when you're confident. Expect all this to take a couple of days.

Comment: @YannicDoNotText: 2.5GB. I had two spreadsheets open, and alt-tabbed into the middle of the wrong one. Calculated as 20 writes per minute; 20*100 (2000) rows per write; 2,880,000 rows per day; 86,400,000 rows per month; 28 bytes per row; 2,419,200,000 bytes per month. That's a lot of rows.

Comment: Yeah. I know. But I have to do that. It is for a monitoring project with 3 month data history... do you think thats possible? With the suggested ERM? The first suggestion with one row and 100 columns is wrong isn't it?

Comment: The first suggestion isn't very good. For one thing, MySQL won't fit very many rows on a page, so there will be a *lot* of disk activity. I'll edit my answer to include some more ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your update! It helps me a lot. Above I wrote that I need to store changing parameters from a pump (count of ~100). My project leader told me that we need to store them every 3s.
It makes it much more difficult that the parameters on multiple pumps are not always the same. So my first guess was the key-value store sytem with the id of the pump and the timestamp.
Meanwhile I think that the best and only way. I can not imagine that a row with 100 cryptic columns is the correct way.

Comment: Test both. Life is full of surprises. And it makes you look like you're open to different ways of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry so much about the database size. Your bigger problem is maintenance and flexibility.

Here's what I would do. First, define and fill this table with possible keys your device can write:

```
tblDataKey
(
    ID int primary key (auto-increment - not sure how mysql does this)
    Name varchar(32)
)
```

Next define a 'data event' table:

```
tblEvent
(
    ID int primary key (auto-inc)
    TimeStamp
    ...anything else you need - device ID's? ...
)
```

Then match events with keys and their values:

```
tblEventData
{
    EventID INT FK-to-tblEvent
    KeyID INT FK-to-tblDataKey
    DataValue varchar(???)
)
```

Now every however-many-seconds your data comes in you create a single entry in tblEvent and multiple entries in tblEventData with key-values as needed. Not every event needs every key, and you can expand on the # of keys in the future.

This really shines in that space isn't wasted and you can easily do queries for evnets with specific data keys and values. Where this kind of structure falls down is when you need to produce 'cross-tab-like' tables of events and data items. You'll have to decide if that's a problem or not.

Comment: Hi n8wrl, thank you for your answer.
I tried it like you described it. Could you take a look at that?
http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/?keyword=tempidi2